# How to get information of the previous object of the file

Tags: python, class, object, file-handling

```
def __init__(self):
    self.name=''
    self.id=''
    self.sal=0.0
    self.allowance=0.4*self.sal
    self.ded = 0.1*self.sal
    self.npay = self.sal+self.allowance-self.ded
def Input(self):
    self.name = raw_input('name')
    self.id = raw_input('id')
    self.sal = float(raw_input("salary"))
def create(self):
    f = open("pay.dat","wb")
    pickle.dump(self,f)
    f.close()
def read_file(self):
    f = open('pay.dat','rb')
    x = pickle.load(f)
    print"_"*45
    print '{0:<15s}{1:15s}{2:15s}'.format("Employee_Id","Name","Basic salary")
    print"_"*45
    print '{0:<15s}{1:15s}{2:15f}'.format(x.id,x.name,x.sal)
    f.close()
def add(self):
    self.Input()
    self.create()
    self.read_file()
```

Note-Pickle was pre-imported, class was made.
when i create an object of the class, is displays all the information in the right sequence. However, when i add new data , it does not print the previous data as well. How do i do that?

Comment: Please avoid mutilating examples like this. It is disturbing to ook at a class ody without the actual class declaration like it is here.

Answer (score 0):

Your create method:

```
def create(self):
    f = open("pay.dat","wb")
    pickle.dump(self,f)
    f.close()
```

Truncates the previous file at 0 bytes, and write the information for the new object everytime it is called. To keep information on the file without truncating it, open it in `"ab"` mode instead of `"wb"` .

That said, your code for reading and displaying information will only read a single object from the file. And even if it was reading more objects, it does not even try to loop on the object read to print information on more than one object.

The only thing that works here is the idea that you can actually pickle several objects in sequence on the same file - and them read them back in sequence.

So, you could rewrite your "read_file" method like the following - but the fact you did not even try to make a loop to iterate over more than one object suggests you have to learn some more in order to better unerstanding this example. Please make sure you get some reading, and pratice on the Python interactive prompt about sequences and loops (`for` and `while`). Here looks like a nice place to get the basics:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

```
def read_file(self):
    print"_"*45
    print '{0:<15s}{1:15s}{2:15s}'.format("Employee_Id","Name","Basic salary")
    print"_"*45
    with (open('pay.dat','rb')) as f:
        while True:
            try:
                x = pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError: 
                # no more objects to read - exit loop
                break 

            print '{0:<15s}{1:15s}{2:15f}'.format(x.id,x.name,x.sal)
```